# ggplot : unable to load shared object '/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/stringi/libs/stringi.so':

Tags: r, linux, ggplot2

I'm trying to get some plotting done but unfortunately it yields this error along with a blank window :

```
ggplot(dt, aes(B, C),) + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ A)
```

> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
>     unable to load shared object '/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
>     libicui18n.so.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: [re]install the `stringi` package?

Comment: @hrbrmstr that worked thanks

Answer (score 2):

[re]install the `stringi` package
                    – hrbrmstr

Comment: I'm on R 4.0.3 Ubuntu 20.04 and suddenly I was unable to knit files after doing a minor upgrade. I was getting the error unable to load shared object '/stringi.so': and reinstalling as per u/Armali was what solved this for me. Thanks!!