# Why won't ggplot install properly on my machine after an upgrade?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stringi

I've had a problem for a while now in which I can't load the stringi package until I install it clean. This seems to work as long as I'm in a single R session. Then, some time later, maybe when I create a new session or probably after a longer delay, I have to install it again.

This all broke this morning for some reason. Now, if I can install it straight away, and load it, but it's not recognized by ggplot2. Specifically when I try to install ggplot2 I get:

```
    > library(stringi)
    > install.packages("ggplot2")
    Installing package into ‘/home/bensmith/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.0.0.tar.gz'

    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2847050 bytes (2.7 MB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 2.7 MB

    * installing *source* package ‘ggplot2’ ...
    ** package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** R
    ** data
    *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
    ** inst
    ** preparing package for lazy loading
    Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
      unable to load shared object '/home/bensmith/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
      /home/bensmith/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so: undefined symbol: R_ContinueUnwind
    ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ggplot2’
    * removing ‘/home/bensmith/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/ggplot2’
    * restoring previous ‘/home/bensmith/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/ggplot2’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

    The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpEStEk4/downloaded_packages’
```

As you can see, stringi loads successfully into the environment, but I get this error when installing ggplot2.

[Elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069014/ggplot-unable-to-load-shared-object-home-user-r-x86-64-pc-linux-gnu-library?rq=1) this problem has been reported as fixed by installing stringi, but here, that doesn't help. But I suspect something is wrong with the stringi installation because of the previous problems I have had having to continually reinstall it.

I have tried installing stringi and ggplot2 using

`install.packages("stringi", type = "source")
install.packages("ggplot2", type = "source")`

Once again, stringi installs but ggplot2 does not.

Comment: Can you restart your R session then try: `install.packages(c("ggplot2"), dependencies = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be installing Rcpp again that fixed the problem.
Thanks to commenter at https://community.rstudio.com/t/stringi-installation-not-recognized-consequently-ggplot-wont-install/11590